# how can I bind a full response from SQLite?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am making a `ListView` inside my C# file. But instead of that I want to add the data I get from sqlite too the xaml file with data binding so I can still edit the layout with xaml. So every response from sqlite needs to be  added as label(`<TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />`).

My question: How can I bind the response from `GetCategoryByMenuID` to TextCell `Text="{Binding Name}"`?

xaml page (CategoriePage.xaml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AmsterdamTheMapV3.CategoriePage">
  <ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Back-end / C# (CategoriePage.xaml.cs) :

```
namespace AmsterdamTheMapV3
{
    public partial class CategoriePage : ContentPage
    {

        public CategoriePage(String txt)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var layout = new StackLayout { Padding = new Thickness(5, 10) };
            int page = Int32.Parse(txt);
            this.Content = layout;

            var categories = App.Database.GetCategoryByMenuID(page);

            var datatemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                var nameLabel = new Label();
                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
                //nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.idProperty, "Name");

                return new ViewCell { View = nameLabel };
            });

            var listView = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = categories,
                ItemTemplate = datatemplate
            };

            layout.Children.Add(listView);
        }
    }
}
```

GetCategoryPage function:

```
public List<Categories> GetCategoryByMenuID(int menuID)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        return db.Table<Categories>().Where(x => x.Menu_ID == menuID).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AmsterdamTheMapV3.CategoriePage">
  <ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <StackLayout>
              <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Update code behind

```
namespace AmsterdamTheMapV3 {
    public partial class CategoriePage : ContentPage {

        public CategoriePage(string txt) {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Appearing += (s,e) => {
                if(NotInDesignMode) {
                    int page = 0;
                    if(int.TryParse(txt, out page)){
                        var categories = App.Database.GetCategoryByMenuID(page);
                        this.listView.ItemsSource = categories;
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        bool NotInDesignMode {
            get { return Application.Current != null; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work because categories is not a String `Error: Input string was not in a correct format`

Comment: Where is that error being thrown? it is most probably when you try to parse the `string` to `int`. The assumption here was that categories was a collection of objects returned from the database call, which allowed for it to be used as an items source for the list view

Comment: The problem is that `var categories` A array is but I can be wrong have some troubles with Xamarin just started with app development.

Comment: new unhandled exception: `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: it proves that the value passed to `txt` is not a valid `int` which is why you were getting `Error: Input string was not in a correct format`. So you need to check what value if being passed to the constructor. This answer is based on what you have in your OP. but there is only so much I can assume based on that if the information in your post is not complete

Comment: Man you did fix it I had a stupid mistake inside my code I change `var txt` but it works now thx man

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the ugly and fast-to-implement way (in your GetCategoryByMenuID method, Run an update name by id, which will run on categories).

Or by making a collection that'd be menuID based instead of index based as a regular list.

```
 public class CategoriesCollection<T> : KeyedCollection<int, T>
    {
        protected override int GetKeyForItem(T item)
        {
            return (item as Category).Id;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to get the index into the List{} in the base collection for an item that may or may 
        /// not be in the collection. Returns -1 if not found.
        /// </summary>
        protected override int GetItemIndex(T itemToFind)
        {
            int keyToFind = GetKeyForItem(itemToFind);
            return BaseList.FindIndex((T existingItem) =>
                                      GetKeyForItem(existingItem).Equals(keyToFind));
        }
    }
```

sql should be OK storing/retrieving anything that's icollection, so while you couldn't use a dictionary, this should work. At least it has worked for me in sqlite (before I've moved away from sqliteAPI to entityframework)

Comment: So ehm I don't get It to work (making a colletion) get lots of errors about unknown names / namespace. Can you give some more explanation about it. Sorry just started with C# and Xamarin.

Comment: This is a image of the error's I get imgur.com/gallery/EeGml. The first error was probally a typo so I did edit you're command.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. First of all https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx, you'd have to add the System.Collections.ObjectModel name. Second I've edited my code- changed the guid to int, which should remove another error